# Sequel way of selecting all records of specific date

Tags: ruby, sequel

What's the best way to select all records of a specific date in Sequel ignoring the time?

Writing a where clause with range from the day's 0 to 23:59 seems to unlike it. Any other way to do?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
Post.where(:created_at => (date.beginning_of_day..date.end_of_day))
```

where date is the Date object

Comment: Just tried Date.today and it seems to work!! It wasn't before or may be my test values where wrong.

Comment: Seems `beginning_of_day` and `end_of_day` are specific to Rails; and not Ruby itself.